# Why does using async mode/queue when parsing with gocolly yield incosistent results?

Tags: go, web-scraping, go-colly

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "strings"
    "sync/atomic"
    "time"

    "github.com/gocolly/colly/v2"
    "github.com/gocolly/colly/v2/queue"
)

func main() {
    c := colly.NewCollector(

    )

    c.SetRequestTimeout(time.Minute * 5)

    queue, _ := queue.New(8, &queue.InMemoryQueueStorage{MaxSize: 1000})

    var (
        visited int64
        cards   []map[string]string
    )

    c.OnHTML("a.css-rc5s2u", func(e *colly.HTMLElement) {
        e.Request.Visit(e.Attr("href"))
    })

    c.OnError(func(r *colly.Response, err error) {
        fmt.Println("Request URL:", r.Request.URL, "failed with response:", r, "\nError:", err)
    })

    c.OnHTML("ul.css-sfcl1s", func(e *colly.HTMLElement) {
        atomic.AddInt64(&visited, 1)
        card := make(map[string]string)
        e.ForEach("p.css-b5m1rv", func(_ int, elem *colly.HTMLElement) {
            text := strings.Split(elem.Text, ":")
            if len(text) > 1 {
                card[text[0]] = text[1]
            } else {
                card["type"] = text[0]
            }
        })
        cards = append(cards, card)

    })

    c.OnRequest(func(r *colly.Request) {
        fmt.Println("Visiting", r.URL)
    })

    const (
        baseURL = "some_url"
        maxPage = 5
    )

    for p := 1; p <= maxPage; p++ {
        urlPath := fmt.Sprintf("%s&page=%d", baseURL, p)
        queue.AddURL(urlPath)
    }

    queue.Run(c)

    fmt.Println(visited)
    fmt.Println(len(cards))
}
```

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "github.com/gocolly/colly/v2"
    "strings"
    "sync/atomic"
    "time"
)

func main() {
    c := colly.NewCollector(
        colly.Async(true),

    )

    c.SetRequestTimeout(5 * time.Minute)

    var (
        visited int64
        cards   []map[string]string
    )

    c.OnHTML("a.css-rc5s2u", func(e *colly.HTMLElement) {
        e.Request.Visit(e.Attr("href"))
    })

    c.OnHTML("ul.css-sfcl1s", func(e *colly.HTMLElement) {
        atomic.AddInt64(&visited, 1)
        card := make(map[string]string)
        e.ForEach("li>p.css-b5m1rv", func(_ int, elem *colly.HTMLElement) {
            text := strings.Split(elem.Text, ":")
            if len(text) > 1 {
                card[text[0]] = text[1]
            } else {
                card["type"] = text[0]
            }
        })
        cards = append(cards, card)

    })

    c.OnRequest(func(r *colly.Request) {
        fmt.Println("Visiting", r.URL)
    })

    const (
        baseURL = "some_url"
        maxPage = 5
    )

    for p := 1; p <= maxPage; p++ {
        urlPath := fmt.Sprintf("%s&page=%d", baseURL, p)
        c.Visit(urlPath)
    }

    c.Wait()

    fmt.Println(visited)
    fmt.Println(len(cards))
}
```

I am using gocolly for web scraping and I don't understand why when using the async mode or a queue, I get inconsistent results for `visited`. I get the value slightly smaller than the expected value as if it didn't have enough time to process all URLs.

Running all URLs consecutively yields the correct result. I have tried playing around with RequestTimeout, but without any success.

Maybe, there is something I am missing in the code that results in inconsistent behavior. For smaller values of `pages`, the results are most often correct.

My guess is that URLs occasionally return an error, but the library doesn't log anything unusual

Comment: "inconsistent results for visited" please explain what you mean (sample output from your app demonstrating the issue would help). You have a [data race](https://go.dev/doc/articles/race_detector) on `cards` so I would not be surprised if the two values output differ.

Comment: For cards, the data race is there, you are right, but for `visited` the counter should be correct. 

I know how many items a page has and thus the total number after all pages have been processed and thus the correct counter value. 

However, it is most often off by a small number. For example, if the correct value is 300, the counter is 295 or 298.